# Help with understanding a normal distribution/probability question

Tags: time-series, correlation, probability

Could someone please help me translate what this is saying on page P15, section 4.2:

http://www.ntuzov.com/Nik_Site/Niks_files/Research/papers/stat_arb/Ahmed_2009.pdf

Specifically:

> When the order rates are time-varying probabilities must be computed
>   via Monte Carlo. A simple algorithm is as follows. There are six types
>   of orders; buy/sell and market/limit/cancel. For each type of order
>   there are multiple rates depending on the distance to the bid/ask,
>   i.e. if the bid is at the tenth highest tick level then there are ten
>   limit buy orders.
>
> Let $\lambda_i$, $i \in \mathcal{I}$ be the collection of all order
>   rates and $\boldsymbol{x}_t = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be the current state
>   of the order book, as specified in [1]. Then there are a fixed and
>   finite number of possible states $x_t+1$ can take on. The next state
>   of the order book is completely determined by which order arrives
>   first. It is known that if $X_i \sim \exp(\lambda_i)$ then
>
> Therefore **to determine the next state of the order book we just
>   sample $u \sim U(0,1)$ then partition the interval $(0, 1)$ according
>   to the above probabilities to determine which order arrived first**.
>   After the next state of the order book is computed we recompute the
>   $\lambda_i$'s since they depend on the order book, i.e. $x_t$ is an
>   inhomogeneous Markov chain, and repeat to generate an entire sample
>   path.
>
> Let $A$ be the set of $\omega$ where the midprice increases, to
>   compute its probability we simulate sample paths until there is a
>   change in the midprice and compute $I_A(\omega)$ then estimate the
>   probability as

EDIT:

Ok, I have made some progress:

As the comment below says, X is exponentially distributed. However, I do not get what calculating the "distribution of the minimum exponential random variable" is for?

Also, once we have done this we then (seem to) plot the uniform distribution between 0 and 1 and then plot the probabilities on the x-axis, and, I think, look for the probability with the greatest area?

**I really don't understand why this tells us the next state?? What exactly is finding the minimum exponential random variable telling us?**

**Why do we need to use the uniform distribution?**

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to understand what you want. What do you mean by "the probability $X_i$ is normally distributed"? The claims that $X_i$ is exponentially distributed.

Comment: Please see edit

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is the following. They want to determine the next state of the order book. So, they need to know which order comes first.

One way to find which order arrives first could be to generate a new $X_i$ for all $i \in \mathcal{I}$, and to identify the smallest. This would not be efficient.
The alternative that they mention relies on
$$
p_k := {\rm Pr}[\min (X_i : i \in \mathcal{I}) = X_k]
= \frac{\lambda_k}{\sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} \lambda_i},
$$
which provides the probability that the $k$th is the smallest. Obviously, these probabilities sum to one. The idea is to partition the interval $[0, 1]$ into disjoint segments of size $p_k$, one for each order $k$. To determine which order comes first, one just needs to sample a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$, and determine in which segment it belongs.

**Edit: example of determination of the first order**
 
Suppose that $\mathcal{I} = \{1, 2, 3\}$, and $\lambda_1 = 2, \lambda_2 = 5, \lambda_3 = 3$. So, $p_1 = 0.2, p_2 = 0.5, p_3 = 0.3$, and the segments are [0, 0.2], (0.2, 0.7] and (0.7, 1].
Let $u$ denote the value sampled from the uniform distribution. If $u \in [0, 0.2]$ then $k = 1$, if $u \in (0.2, 0.7]$ then $k = 2$, and if $u \in (0.7, 1]$ then $k = 3$.

Comment: Thanks for this. My question is thus- the sum of lambda_i will not change for each lambda_k we calculate. As we also have a uniform distribution- so wouldn't the largest probability simply be the largest lambda_k?

Comment: I don't get it. If one $\lambda_k$ changes, then $\sum \lambda_k$ will change. For the simulation, if you pick the $k$ having the largest $\lambda_k$, say $\tilde{k}$, then you pick $\tilde{k}$ with probability one, which is not equal to $p_{\tilde{k}}$.

Comment: No what I mean is, when calculating each X_k you divide lambda_k by the sum of all lambda_i. The sum of all lambda_i value will be the same for each calculation of X_k, surely?

Comment: From the article: "After the next state of the order book is computed we recompute the $\lambda_i$ ’s since
they depend on the order book".

Comment: Yes I didn't mean that part. I meant when we calculate each X_k on the first run, the equation is lambda_k divided by the sum of lambda_i. Now the sum of lambda_i will be the same for every calculation of lambda_k.... because the set doesn't change whilst we do this calculation. So for every calculation of lambda_k, it will be lambda_i divided by the same sum each time. As we are dividing through by the same sum every time, surely this is pointless and the largest probability will just be the largest lambda_i?

Comment: Yes, within one iteration $\sum \lambda_k$ is constant, and the $k$ with the largest $\lambda_k$ will also have the largest $p_k$. But what do you infer from that?

Comment: This is the part I don't get- the next part of the paper says to plot the uniform distribution and "according to the above probabilities to determine which order arrived first". The above probabilities are going to be proportional to lambda_i. I dont understand how plotting them on the uniform distribution would give the next book state. If you could shed any light on this, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: I don't see were they say to plot the uniform distribution. The "according to the above probabilities to determine which order arrived first" is what I explained in the last two sentences of my answer. See edit for an example.

Comment: Ok- they didn't say "plot" but thats what I did to try and understand what was happening. Could you say in basic terms why we are using the uniform distribution and how exactly does the uniform distribution, along with the probabilities calculated previously, determine which event is most likely to happen next? Thanks

Comment: That is exactly what is explained in the answer. I can't explain it in more basic terms. It seems that I won't be able to help you further on this.

Comment: This is the bit I dont get (I get everything else): "Let u denote the value sampled from the uniform distribution". What exactly is u here? I understand you've got <this value> and you're now looking at the uniform distribution (graph?) to see which of the 3 areas it lies in, but where does u come from and what type of value is it? Thanks for the ongoing help